# Postgres database deadlock issue

Tags: postgresql, deadlock

I am using Cloudera Manager to monitor and configure Hadoop. I choose PostgreSQL as metastore of HUE - a web portal to submit your SQL to Hadoop.

When I submit a SQL, the HUE says the database is locked. I don't have any database management experience.

So, how to find the root cause and diagnose?

I try to connect to the database `postgres` which I believe this is the meta-database of PostgreSQL itself. I expect I can find the processes, events and lock information in this database.

```
postgres=> \c postgres
Password for user hue:
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "hue".
postgres=> \d
No relations found.
postgres=>
```

I connect to this database - 'postgres' as user - 'HUE'. But I didn't find any tables under it. Am I using the wrong user?

How can I access this database successfully? How can I discover why the database is locked? Where is it locked? On which table and which database?

Comment: Read on the Postgres documentation online: [Lock Monitoring](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring)

Answer (score 3):

Your software is most likely not using the default `postgres` database (that is a database that is normally reserved only to store the list of databases, users, and other globals).

From psql, run `\l` to list the available databases. Your database will be something other than postgres, template0, or template1. Try connecting to one that is not one of the above (`\c dbname`) and then run `\d` again to list tables.

Comment: Thanks. I know the user database should not be postgres, template0, template1. What I want to know is how to analysis deadlock problem. I believe that I can get some informations from some system databases and tables about the dead lock.

Comment: With PgAdmin3, menu _Tools / Server Status_, you can see what's going on and what statement is locking which resources and/or other statements, refreshed periodically.

Comment: I can see the real time deadlock through the tool/server status, how can I know how many dead locks in the history?

Comment: @cdhit you can't, deadlocks are not (normally, or AFAIK not at all possibly) logged. Have a look at [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring), or see what you find googling "postgresql log deadlock"